# Accessing user D2L user info via flash

Tags: flash, variables, desire2learn

Can a flash file embedded in a D2L content page access D2L user ID information and store this information in a variable? If so, how can this be done?

I appreciate any help the community can provide!

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to do this is via a SCORM object (aka a SCO). SCORM is not strictly for flash, but it is quite common to see SCORM packages that essentially host a flash based learning activity. The SCORM model allows a rich exchange of learner information from the LMS, and the results are stored and report-able later in the LMS. In fact, SCOs can even have their results pushed to the gradebook. SCORM packages will also work in pretty much any other LMS.

It *might* be possible to do what you want in other ways, but for interactive flash content, this is the easiest.

If you are not familiar with SCORM, it's a well documented and widely used standard, see http://www.adlnet.gov/scorm/scorm-version-1-2/ for the official docs, and the first Google page on SCORM for lots of other great references.

Regards,
Matt

Comment: Matthew is correct.  You'd have to use a Flash to ExternalInterface call to JavaScript to communicate with back to the D2L SCORM Runtime.  I've got JavaScript and Flash AS3 code up on https://github.com/cybercussion/SCOBot.  You'd have to request 'cmi.core.student_id'.  See more about API support https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3459294/SCOBot-Content-API-Standards-Breakdown.pdf.